# get the list of remembered Network Profiles of a Windows computer over ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-registry, cygwin

AFAIK, Windows remembers the *network locations* you've connected to (and tagged as *Guest*, *Work* or *Home*). It identifies them based on (possibly among other things) the domain name returned by the DHCP server and the MAC address of the default gateway.

On Windows 7 home at least, with the `regedit` GUI, and as an admin user, I can get that information from `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList`.

However, when using `reg query` or `regedit /e` to get that information from the command line like:

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList" /s
```

I'm denied access `NetworkList` and any of its sub-keys.

That works from an elevated `cmd.exe`.

If I try to run that command over Cygwin `sshd` (using `reg` or `/proc/registry`) or via kaspersky security center remote diagnostics utility (which lets me run commands on remote machines) or with SysInteral `psexec`, then I can access `NetworkList` but none of its sub-keys (no output returned). That part I can reproduce on Win7 Enterprise, Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 as well.

So how could one get access to those restricted section of the registry from Cygwin `sshd`.

Alternatively, is there another way to access the list of network profiles (the information I'm most interested in is the *DateCreated*, *DateLastConnected*, *Category* (public, private), *ProfileName* (or any indication of what the SSID might have been for wifi networks), *DnsSuffix* and *DefaultGatewayMac*) that doesn't have such restrictions (from `sshd`).

Or Alternatively, how to get access to the registry files or any other method I can get to that information from `sshd` on Window 7 home, 8.1 or 10?

If anyone can explain the mechanism by which those seem to be hidden from me (AFAICT, the ACL for NetworkList is the same as for its parent or its subkeys), that would be great.

Comment: it works for me if the userid of the ssh user is an administrator

Comment: @matzeri, what version/variant of Windows? It doesn't work for me in Win7 home

Comment: Windows 7 Professional

Comment: @matzeri do you deploy `sshd` in any special way (other than running `ssh-host-config`?). I just tested that it doesn't work for me in Win10, Win7 enterprise, win8.1. Tested with `ssh admin@host "reg query 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles' /s"`.

Comment: Nothing special that I remember. From ssh -v before password I see `debug1: Next authentication method: password` and the password is the Windows one.